# Solutions to $\sigma(a^2)=\sigma(b^2)$ [divisor sum function]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An exercise in Burton's "Elementary Number Theory" [7 e.d. p 111 prob. 13]  asks that one show there are infinitely many pairs $a,b$ of (positive) integers for which $\sigma(a^2)=\sigma(b^2),$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the positive divisors of $n.$ He gives a hint, and my question is whether the hint describes all the solutions. The hint: Let $a=4k,b=5k$ where $k>0$ and $\gcd(k,10)=1.$

Since $\sigma(4^2)=\sigma(5^2)=31,$ use of the multiplicative property of $\sigma$ finishes the exercise. I did a moderate search and didn't find any not covered by the given hint. That is, I could ask whether there are positive $a<b$ for which $\sigma(a^2)=\sigma(b^2)$ and $b/a$ is *not* $5/4.$ [Not quite exactly the denial that the exercise describes all solutions, but I'd be satisfied with a decision one way or the other on this version.]

Thanks for any info/solutions.

Comment: Comments: the [Goormaghtigh conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goormaghtigh_conjecture) implies that this is the only infinite family of the form $a=q_1k$, $b=q_2k$ where $q_1,q_2$ are prime powers. Note the first solution there corresponds to the values $\sigma(5^2)$ and $\sigma(2^4)$. If there is any other solution $\sigma(c^2)=\sigma(d^2)$, then $a=ck$, $b=dk$ for $(k,cd)=1$ is another infinite family of solutions.

Comment: Try $a=326, b=407$. If you search for qualifying values of $a,b$ with $a < b < 10^4$, you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: @quasi Thanks for that example, and the heads up about lots of solutions. My software to look for examples is limited, unfortunately.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for that reference-- will look at it.